# Renaming an image with a number inside a text file

Tags: shell, scripting, file-rename

I have a folder containing images and textfiles. 
The image name is in this order: tramnummerx.JPG
The text file is in this order : tramnummerx.txt

*to be clear: x is a variable number*

Inside the .txt is a 4 digit number, for example 6303.
In this case I would like to rename the .JPG file to : tramnummerx-6303.JPG

In my current script I did this:

```
x=O
extention='*.txt'
for i in 'ls $extention'
do
x = 'expr $x + 1'
y= ??? the command for extracting the number ???
mv tramnummerx.JPG tramnummerx-$y.JPG
done
```

I tried some things like `awk '{print $(NF-1), $NF;}' filename` for "y=" but I just ended up deleting my files this way.

Thanks in advance!

SOLUTION:

```
for i in 'ls $extention'
do
x='expr $x +1'
read y < tramnummer$x.txt
mv tramnummer$x.JPG tramnummer$x-$y.JPG
done
```

Comment: Instead of setting $extention and then using `ls` to list the file names, just do `for i in *.txt`.  That copes better in case you have file names with spaces in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expression matching to extract the number from the image file name, and `read` to extract the new number from the corresponding text file. (Some details may need adjusting if I misunderstood your question, but the general approach will stay the same.)

```
for img in *.JPG; do
    [[ $img =~ tramnummer([[:digit:]]+).JPG ]]
    x=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    read y < tramnummer$x.txt
    mv tramnummer$x.JPG tramnummer$x-$y.JPG
done
```

---

In your existing code, you could use lines like

```
x=$(( x + 1 ))
y=$(< tramnummer$x.txt )
```

but the proposed solution is a little cleaner and more idiomatic.